# Number of ways to divide a line of length $s$ into segments such that each segment has length $\leq n$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This is a slightly modified version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413645/number-of-ways-to-divide-a-stick-of-integer-length-n-take-2). With a line of length $s$ and an integral length $n$, I must divide $s$ into $\left \lceil{\frac{s}{n}}\right \rceil$ segments such that union of all segments gives $s$. Constraint is that none of the segments should have length $> n$.

Is a closed form solution possible for $f(s,n)$? Since with the given constraints I'm unable to reach anywhere.

Example: for a given $s = 6$ and $n = 4$.

The possible combinations are (1-4, 5-6), (1-3, 4-6), (1-2, 3-6) => So $$f(6,4) = 3$$

Comment: Do each you need the segments to have strictly positive length, or is a segment allowed to have length $0$ (in other words, do you need to use *exactly*  $\left\lceil\frac{s}n\right\rceil$ segments or are we allowed to use less)?

Comment: Is it possible for one segment to have length $0$ without another having length $>n$?

Comment: I think you are right @ConnorHarris. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "initialize" all segments to have length $n$ precisely. Now you have cut up a stick of length
$$
\left\lceil\frac sn \right\rceil \cdot n, 
$$
which is
$$
\left\lceil\frac sn \right\rceil \cdot n - s = n-(s \% n)
$$
too long, where $s\%n$ uses the "computer science modulo operator", i.e. the remainder of $s$ after dividing by $n$. Thus, you need to shorten your segments by a total of $n-(s\%n)$. Because $0 < s\%n < n$ always, you have no further constraints: you could allocate all these "units of shortening" to one segment, or to all different ones. This is a typical [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem, and the number of ways of doing it is given by
$$
\binom{n-(s \% n) + \lceil s/n\rceil - 1}{\lceil s/n \rceil-1}.
$$
**Edit**: Actually, the above only works when $n$ does not precisely divide $s$. However, that special case is easy: there is only one solution. All sticks have length precisely $s/n$, which is now an integer.

Comment: won't this give 10 for $s=6$, $n$=4, rather than 3?

Comment: @IndoUbt, my bad; what I called $n$ in the final formula is supposed to be the number of segments, i.e. $\lceil s/n \rceil$. I will update it now.