# Algorithm to obtain a magic rectangle of order $3\times 128$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, magic-square

Is there an computer program/ spreadsheet to obtain a magic rectangle of dimensions- $3\times 128.$ Please suggest me an simple algorithm so that i can build it myself if possible.

Comment: Remind us, what is a magic rectangle?

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews, Thank you for your keen interest. I was introduced to the concept of Magic Rectangles through this thread- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/295871/654225. Please use this alternative link if this dosent work- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83732/number-of-ways-to-divide-a-stick-of-integer-length-n